# Terminaison après « qu'a »

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé

Quelle est la bonne terminaison dans la phrase suivante?

> Je me souviens des discussions télévisées qu’a suscit**ées** ce livre.

ou

> … qu'a susci**té** ce livre.

Je vous serais très reconnaissant!

Answer (score 0):

Votre première réponse est tout à fait correcte:

> et je me souviens des discussions télévisées qu’a suscit**ées** ce livre

Lorsque le complément d'objet direct ( *discussions télévisées*) est placé avant le verbe (*suciter*), il y a  accord en genre et en nombre entre le COD et le participe passé.